# Blazor component ref Field is never assigned to

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I cannot find Why isnt this working. Probably just me beign dumb.

My Modal Component receives a TItem that can hide and close. Ive looked to MSDOCS but i think its exactly the same thing.

```
@typeparam TItem

<div class="bmodal-bg" @onclick="Close">
    <div class="bmodal" style="@Style" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">
        @ModalContent(Item)
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TItem> ModalContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public TItem Item { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> OnModalClose { get; set; }

    private bool IsOpen { get; set; } = false;

    public void Show()
    {
        IsOpen = true;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

I created a ref to my modal component that receives a TItem.

```
        private UIFuncionario NewFuncionario { get; set; } = new UIFuncionario();
        private Modal<UIFuncionario> ModalAddFuncionario;
```

The part where i make the reference

```
<Modal @ref="ModalAddFuncionario" Item="NewFuncionario">
    <ModalContent Context="p">
        <FormFuncionario Funcionario="p" />
    </ModalContent>
</Modal>
```

[enter Error when you remove UIFuncionario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlKck.png)
[Edit: Message of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvT8y.png)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, references are populated on the OnAfterRender event. If the modal component you're using has animations maybe you'll need a Task.Delay(20) before this can get the ref, so that the child component OnAfterRender fires and populates the ref

Edit: add getter and setter to the ref field

Comment: Thanks i will try it.

Comment: I added a image that shows the error it persists even with the added {get; set;}  the timing is not a problem because i only call the show method on a button.

Comment: Have you tried using OnAfterRender? Even with button clicks you still get an EventCallback that redraws a bunch of the page And OnAfterRender fires again and then you have refs

Comment: The problem is that it never get a value its always null, I think something goes wrong because i use typeparam

Answer (score 1):

Im dumb. I just missed @ > @onclick. The reference was working. Sorry.